# JAVA removing a line from a .txt file with a keyword

Tags: java

```
try {

      File inFile = new File("books.txt");

      if (!inFile.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
        return;
      }

      //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename. 
      File tempFile = new File(inFile + "temp.txt");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("books.txt"));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

      String line = null;

      //Read from the original file and write to the new 
      //unless content matches data to be removed.
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String lineToRemove;
        lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter line to remove");
        if (!line.trim().contains(lineToRemove)) {

          pw.println(line);
          pw.flush();
        }
      }
      pw.close();
      br.close();

      //Delete the original file
      if (!inFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      } 

      //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
      if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I am trying to create a method that will delete a line of code in my .txt file if I enter a word that is contained in that line. My problem is that when I run this, the test says that it could not delete the file. Is there something wrong with the code? My code is also delimited with # if that may be adding to the problem. A sample output would be :
     Giants#James#1993

Comment: Don't use `File.delete`, use [`Files.delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-). This will throw a helpful exception to indicate the cause of failure; as opposed to returning a `boolean` with not indication of the reason.

Comment: inFile.delete() returns false, that means books.txt is not present.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare so very untrue. It could be a permissions problem, for example. It could be present but not a file. It could be a dozen other things.

Comment: I have a books.txt file. I'm sure.

Comment: Unrelated, but why use `new FileReader("books.txt")` when you have a `File` object with the name? `new FileReader(inFile)` would be better. --- Why do you prompt for `lineToRemove` for every single line in the input file? --- Why do you `flush()` every single line written? There is no need to flush, at all. --- Why call `trim()` to remove leading and trailing spaces when you then use `contains()` that search for a substring, and therefore doesn't care about leading and trailing spaces? --- And finally, please use try-with-resources, and the new `Path`/`Files` API.

Comment: In general, the Windows Operating System does not allow a file to be deleted if it is open. Make sure the original file is closed before trying to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code with minor changes (noted by @Andreas while I was writing this) and it works as expected

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

          File inFile = new File("C:\\rirubio\\books.txt");

          if (!inFile.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
            return;
          }

          //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename. 
          File tempFile = new File("C:\\rirubio\\books.txt" + "_temp");

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
          PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

          String line = null;

          String lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter line to remove");

          //Read from the original file and write to the new 
          //unless content matches data to be removed.
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.trim().contains(lineToRemove)) {
              pw.println(line);
              pw.flush();
            }
          }

          pw.close();
          br.close();

          //Delete the original file
          if (!inFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
          } 

          //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
          if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile)) {
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");
          }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I don't know if it was something in my code but I tried the code and it deleted the line and the file.